# Not sure how to solve this conflict

Tags: delphi, user-interface

My Delphi application has 2 activities that (seemingly) must both occur in the UI thread.  In most respects, it is a single-threaded application.  I'm partly having a problem here because I have used Application.ProcessMessages and I do wish to minimize this because of the problems it can cause.

I will first describe the ingredients and then the problem.

The application can open multiple "document" forms but for simplicity, I shall only refer to one document form.  Each form can communicate with external equipment.

There are situations that can arise where the program is built to loop until a certain situation with the equipment allows us to exit the loop *or* the user cancels the operation.  The equipment interface isn't threaded and must be polled.

Here's the problem:

When the user wants to close the document, we *may* be in one of those loops.  That's a problem because all of this is in the UI thread...I don't have a good way to break the loop in the document form so I can close the document.

while not (DeviceReady or CancelKeyPressed) do
  Application.ProcessMessages;

**Original solution:**

My original solution was to do the following when the user tried to close the document:

1. post a user Windows message to the document form telling it we want to close.
2. the document form receives the message and breaks any active loop and send a message back to the main form saying we're ready to close.
3. the main form loops, processes messages and polls checking to see if the document is ready to close.
4. when the document is ready to close, it will complete the closing of the document.

This works most of the time but it is complex--especially because we have multiple documents open at one time.

**Other possible solutions**

- because it would seem to me that all of this must occur in the main thread, moving it to a thread doesn't sound like a solution.
- had thought of letting the document close asynchronously but we need to know when the document closure is complete so we can let the user do something else like open another document.
- the loops are quite fast; 1) send the "stop" message  2) wait ___ ms and process messages to let it work  3) close it.  I think this would be a low quality design that would be weak.
- convert this loop instead into a state machine.  The (legacy) equipment interface isn't threaded and must be polled.  I'd need to make a thread that does the polling and post a message to the form to cause an event.  Then, if such an event occurs or a key is pressed, an event will occur that will cause the next state to occur.  This way, if the form were to be closed, it wouldn't ever be a problem.  Regrettably, effort would be required to convert the surrounding code to participate in the state machine as well.  (that's not all bad.)

**Conclusions**

Application.ProcessMessages seems like a drug...start using it & soon you need to use it even more!

Anyone have any suggestions how better to handle this kind of problem?

Answers to your questions:

(I posted this question to get some opinions on which way I should go with this; I'm a developer working alone and this is something where it made sense to ask the community for some sage advice...)

thank you for your comments!

> How are these "Documents" managed/referenced?

the document forms are standard delphi TForm descendants owned by an object list.

> The rule of multi-threading is, if you need a continuous loop which could cause the main thread to not respond, it should be in the form of a thread. Why aren't you allowed to put it elsewhere? Why must it be in the main thread?

the trouble is that the whole application needs to wait until either the operation completes or it is cancelled by the user.  I suppose I could pass all the incoming keys to the thread.  when the thread sees the loop exit condition met, it could advise the UI thread.

> I like the state machine approach.

so do I...it has a certain elegance and simplicity to it.  It could also simplify some other related systems.

> Why can't you talk to the "equipment" from threads? I would break that part from the UI.

Probably that's what I should do.  The only call I need is thread-safe.

> There are many times people may tell you that it's a common mistake to move things into a thread just to improve performance. But this is one prime example of why you should. I can't imagine any interface which strictly requires the main UI thread. Are you using components dropped-in to the form designer? If that's your setback, have you tried dynamically creating those components in a different thread?

the components include a ribbon and yes, all are created from the UI thread.  Had assumed I couldn't safely create components in another thread and put them on a form the user will interact with.  Surely that wouldn't actually function properly?

I have enough experience with threads I could actually do that but wanted to be more sure there wasn't something obvious I was missing.

Comment: This is very difficult to understand since I can't see your code. How are you currently performing this "loop"? How are these "Documents" managed/referenced? The rule of multi-threading is, if you need a continuous loop which could cause the main thread to not respond, it should be in the form of a thread. Why aren't you allowed to put it elsewhere? Why must it be in the main thread?

Comment: I like the state machine approach.

Comment: Why can't you talk to the "equipment" from threads? I would break that part from the UI.

Comment: There are many times people may tell you that it's a common mistake to move things into a thread just to improve performance. But this is one prime example of why you should. I can't imagine any interface which strictly requires the main UI thread. Are you using components dropped-in to the form designer? If that's your setback, have you tried dynamically creating those components in a different thread?

Comment: Thank you all for your comments!  I took the unusual step of replying to them at the end of the question itself.  I think the consensus is that this will best be done with a thread or a state machine.  I shall need to look deeper and make a choice.  Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is very simple:

Build a base class for the documents and put the base functions (process some action in the background) in there

```
unit BaseDocument;

interface

uses
  System.Classes,
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Threading;

type
  TBaseDocument = class
  private
    FIsReady: Boolean;
    FIsReadyChanged: TNotifyEvent;
    procedure SetIsReady( const Value: Boolean );
    procedure SetIsReadyChanged( const Value: TNotifyEvent );
  protected
    procedure PerformBackgroundAction( AProc: TProc );
  public
    property IsReady: Boolean read FIsReady;
    property IsReadyChanged: TNotifyEvent read FIsReadyChanged write SetIsReadyChanged;
  end;

implementation

{ TBaseDocument }

procedure TBaseDocument.PerformBackgroundAction( AProc: TProc );
begin
  SetIsReady( False );
  TTask.Run( nil,
      procedure
    begin
      try
        AProc( );
      finally
        TThread.Synchronize( nil,
            procedure
          begin
            SetIsReady( True );
          end );
      end;
    end );
end;

procedure TBaseDocument.SetIsReady( const Value: Boolean );
begin
  if FIsReady <> Value
  then
    begin
      FIsReady := Value;
      if Assigned( FIsReadyChanged )
      then
        FIsReadyChanged( Self );
    end;
end;

procedure TBaseDocument.SetIsReadyChanged( const Value: TNotifyEvent );
begin
  FIsReadyChanged := Value;
end;

end.
```

As you can see, we have an `IsReady` as an indicator for the UI part, if the document is ready or not and also an event firing when `IsReady` is changing its state.

Now we need a base document form to handle this. That is easy as well, because we only want to keep the user away from clicking around on the controls. We just put a something (here a `ActivityLayout : TLayout` with `TLayout.Hittest` set to `True`) over all of the forms content.

The `ActivityLayout` contains a black rectangle with opacity set to 30% to darken the forms content and an `TAiniIndicator` to have some information to the user that there is still some action in progress.

Once the document changes the `IsReady` state the form gets informed and shows or hides the `ActivityLayout`.

```
unit Form.BaseDocument;

interface

uses
  BaseDocument,

  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.Objects, FMX.Layouts;

type
  TBaseDocumentForm = class( TForm )
    ActivityLayout: TLayout; { container for ActivityIndicators }
    ActivityCurtain: TRectangle; { darken the form content }
    ActivityIndicator: TAniIndicator; { shows an animation while activity is in progress }
    procedure FormCloseQuery( Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean );
  private
    FDocument: TBaseDocument;
    function CanFormClose: Boolean;
  protected
    procedure SetDocument( ADocument: TBaseDocument );
    procedure DoShowActivity( const AVisible: Boolean );
    procedure DocumentIsReadyChanged( Sender: TObject );
    procedure DoReloadDocument; virtual;
  public

  end;

var
  BaseDocumentForm: TBaseDocumentForm;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}
{ TBaseDocumentForm }

function TBaseDocumentForm.CanFormClose: Boolean;
begin
  Result := not Assigned( FDocument ) or Assigned( FDocument ) and FDocument.IsReady;
end;

procedure TBaseDocumentForm.DocumentIsReadyChanged( Sender: TObject );
begin
  DoShowActivity( not FDocument.IsReady );
  if FDocument.IsReady
  then
    DoReloadDocument;
end;

procedure TBaseDocumentForm.DoReloadDocument;
begin
  // override this to load the document after being ready
end;

procedure TBaseDocumentForm.FormCloseQuery( Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean );
begin
  CanClose := CanFormClose;
end;

procedure TBaseDocumentForm.SetDocument( ADocument: TBaseDocument );
begin
  if FDocument <> ADocument
  then
    begin
      if Assigned( FDocument ) and ( FDocument.IsReadyChanged = DocumentIsReadyChanged )
      then
        FDocument.IsReadyChanged := nil;

      FDocument := ADocument;

      if Assigned( FDocument )
      then
        begin
          FDocument.IsReadyChanged := DocumentIsReadyChanged;
          DocumentIsReadyChanged( FDocument );
        end
      else
        DoShowActivity( False );
    end;
end;

procedure TBaseDocumentForm.DoShowActivity( const AVisible: Boolean );
begin
  ActivityLayout.Visible := AVisible;
  if AVisible
  then
    begin
      { just to ensure the right order }
      ActivityLayout.BringToFront;
      ActivityCurtain.BringToFront;
      ActivityIndicator.BringToFront;
    end;
end;

end.
```

This can easily be extended to work with an interruptible background action too and a cancel button on the `ActivityLayout`.

---

**PS**

**Thread Safe** is only needed, if more than one thread is executing, accessing the same at the same time. If you can ensure, that it will only be accessed by one thread at a given time span then there is no need to have it thread safe.

Comment: Thank you for an interesting solution; it has certainly broadened my way of thinking of this problem.  My app is a VCL application but that doesn't much change the usefulness of your suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

You say that your loops are quite fast but it seems that they are not fast enough. Now I asume you aready try to make them faster so I won't suggest this.

But what you have probably forgot is the fact that it is posible to break the loop in the middle of its cycle using Break command. So perhaps you should check to see if there are psoible places within the loop cycle where you could check the value of CancelKeyPressed and then call Break command with which you will end your loop prematurely.

```
while not (DeviceReady or CancelKeyPressed) do 
begin
  //Do some work
  ...
  //Check if premature exit condition is set
  if CancelKeyPressed then
  begin
    //Do some clean up if needed
    ...
    Break;
  end;
  //Do some more work
  ...
  //Check again if premature exit condition is set
  if CancelKeyPressed then
  begin
    //Do some clean up if needed
    ...
    Break;
  end;
  Application.ProcessMessages;
end;
```

Now you should pay special atention when using Break command especially if you are dynamically creating and freeing some objects inside the loop. Why?

Becouse placing break command on wrong place could prevent some of those objects being freed up properly and will thus lead to memory leaks.

In such cases you would want to make sure that before Break command is being called after you free up all of those objects. So either make sure that break is placed after already existing code that does the freeing or add aditional code that will do the freeing only when loop premature exit condition is set.

And speaking of controlling the loops you might want to check the Continue command which alows you to break the current loop cycle and proceed to the next.

Now this command isn't commonly used becouse you can achieve similar thing by simply putting various blocks of your loop code inside the if stamtents. So if certain condition is met that code is executed else it is not and you could already be at the end of the loop cycle.

Anywhay the main reason why I'm recomending you to check the ability to prematurely end you loops is that even if you do implement multithreading you would still have to wait for your loops to end. Especially if at the end of each loop cycle you update some of your UI controls with the help of Syncronize command.

You wouldn't want to destroy the form and then leave your other thread to try and update now nonexistant UI components would you? I gues not as that would result in bunch of Access Violations.

So what I'm recomending is that first you check to see if there is a way to prematurely end your loops. And then I also recomend you that you try to move that code into seperate threads.

And the main reason for this is the fact that your common use of Application.ProcessMessages is probably the main reason for lowering performance of your loops since the loop won't continue untill Application.ProcessMessages finishes its work.

Comment: Thank you; I'm actually quite familiar with the Break keyword and use it regularly.  I'm aware there is a performance penalty associated with using Application.ProcessMessages.  At the time when the product was originally built, it was a solution to get the job done.  Your solution will not address my needs.

Comment: I never expected this alone to fix your problem. As I don't think that moving the loop code into seperate threads will unless the Application.ProcessMessages calls that you could avoid with proper implementation of multithreading are the main cause for slowdowns.. But even with multithreading you might still need to wait for your loop cycle to end before you go destroying form. And if this takes to long you would still be facing similar problem as now. SO as I have written my suggestion is to try using this with the combination of multithreading.